# Dozens of new Wired Ethernet Network Connections appeared in Networks list

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet, wired

Suddenly new Ethernet Wired Networks started to appear and now I have dozens of them in the list. After opening **All Settings > Networks** there's a list of all of them. I assume about a hundred of them. They are all named "Wired" and only information is "unmanaged" and Hardware address which is different for every single one. There's also the "real" Wired connection on the bottom of the list which says "cable unplugged". I'm connected via WiFi and I've never been connected to this computer via cable.

Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour and how to solve it?

[image: => LINK: "Picture of All Settings -> Networks"]

Comment: Did you start virtual machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out... it was caused by running Docker Containers.

Simply stopping and removing the containers solved this issue.